# laravel route fix needed

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project which I run from my local apache server directory. 
The link for accessing this project is

```
www.localhost/project.dev/public/index.php
```

And I have a navigation menu

[image: navigation menu]

After I have set the APP_URL in .env file to

```
 http://localhost/blog.dev/public/index.php/
```

I get no problems while navigating through the About and Contact pages in the project but when I access the Home page the browser goes to the

```
 http://localhost/
```

but not to the

```
 http://localhost/blog.dev/public/index.php/
```

How can I fix it? Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@getAbout');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');
```

Comment: if you have the public folder in the url you did something wrong

Comment: You've presumably gone and put `<a href="/">`. You'll want `<a href="{{ url('/') }}">` to account for the fact that the site's in a folder.

Comment: @jycr753 I generally agree there, but it's usually OK for local development in a pinch.

Comment: It's not the public folder. In the public folder I just keep the views. In the routes I go to the controller and from the controller I return the View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to setup a vhost in apache. if you want to work like this in your .env set the APP_URL= http://localhost/blog.dev/public/

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan serve` in command line. The laravel buil-in server will active. And you will able to access your laravel application using correct url as like `http://localhost:8000` try this and let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: it works but I don't want it to run as a background process. I would like to try to understand how to fix it when running it from the apache web server

Comment: You have to do vertual host for laravel application. So you have to kow how to make virtual host for laravel application or you can use Laragon which is smiliar other package as like xampp or wampp or mamp. It's awesome package for windows and you don't need to make virtual host manually. Laragon will auto setup virtual hosting for your web application. Like your project name is blog then you will able to access your application using`http://blog.dev`

Comment: The problem that I am on mac :) Thank you! I have fixed it by using the apache virtual host!